# how to select second object's second element with same classname in protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

[HTML Coded snippet is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgv1o.png)

Using protractor, when am writing the following code, am only able to select the **3rd element** from the first matching class

```
var items = element(by.css('.swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box')).all(by.tagName('label'));
items.get(2).click();
```

What would be the way to select **2nd element** from the second matching class?

The code snippet is in the attached image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its `element.all(by.css('.swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box')).each(function (element, index) {`

Comment: Explain the changes you have made and the fix you applied. Posting code alone is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can just *chain* `element()` and `all()`:

```
$$('.swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box').get(1).all(by.tagName("label")).get(1);
```

where `$$` is a shortcut to `element.all(by.css("..."))`.

---

Or, an alternative approach would be to use a single CSS selector with the help of [`nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) and [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) pseudo classes:

```
$(".swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box:nth-of-type(1) label:nth-child(1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. Here is what I did to select the third element of the second matching DIV:

```
element.all(by.css('.swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box label')).
      each(function(element, index) {
        element.getText().then(function(text) {
          if (text === waist) {
            element.click();
          }
          if (text === length) {
            element.click();
          }
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.get(1)`, `.get(2)`, `.get(3)`, etc. now you can use more readable functions like `.second()`, `.third()`, `.fourth()` etc. - I developed a small package - https://github.com/Marketionist/protractor-numerator - that can be used with protractor to select second, third, fourth, etc. elements.

So, applied to your case (to select 2nd element from the second matching class), it would be much more readable and will look like this:

```
var itemSecond = element.all(by.css('.swatches.swatches_size.swatches_find-box')).second().all(by.tagName('label')).second();
itemSecond.click();
```